# sending a post request, but server receives empty data

Tags: vuejs2

I'm doing an http request with "Vue.http", but the data is not sent.

On the server side, the controller method is hit, but the request is empty.

```
   console.log(email, username, password) // NOT EMPTY
   Vue.http({
        url: 'auth/signup',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password
        }
    })
```

Is there something wrong with "data:" ?

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```
Vue.http.post('auth/signup', {
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password
    })
```

I must have used an older "Vue.http" syntax.